# Pusher duplicates and receive multiple data in single push

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pusher

i am using pusher and when android activity restarts, my pusher connection duplicates values 2,3,4 times when i trigger pusher debug console to push. here is the code sample.

```
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();

Pusher pusher ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    options.setCluster("ap3");
    pusher = new Pusher("<key>", options);

    Log.i("PusherConnecting", "Connecting to Pusher");
    pusher.connect();
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

        channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {

                try {

                    Log.i("PusherData", event.getData());
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.i("Error", ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the activity destroy, you can make it much better with onDestroy method. find the below full code of activity. you have to disconnect pusher onDestroy method of activity.

```
 package com.example.pushertest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pusher.client.Pusher;
import com.pusher.client.PusherOptions;
import com.pusher.client.channel.Channel;
import com.pusher.client.channel.PusherEvent;
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionStateChange;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();

Pusher pusher ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    options.setCluster("ap3");
    pusher = new Pusher("<key>", options);

    Log.i("PusherConnecting", "Connecting to Pusher");
    pusher.connect();
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

        channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {

                try {

                    Log.i("PusherData", event.getData());
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.i("Error", ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    pusher.disconnect();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(1);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```